# When/where would want to attach other classes to the base class in a WordPress plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, hooks, init

I have two plugins I'm looking at currently. Each has a function called `plugin_classes` which attaches other classes to the base class.

Both of these plugins have `init` and `hooks` functions.

In the first the call to `$this->plugin_classes()` occurs in the `hooks` function while in the second it is called in the `init` function.

In both cases the `hooks` functions call the `init` functions.

So AFAIK it seems that there is no real difference other than in the plugin using `init` the classes are added slightly after those in hooks (potentially). Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer that without some additional code to accompany it as those aren't WordPress core functions and could be doing anything really.  Based on a previous question, I'll assume one of the plugins you're referring to is the [LiquidChurch/lqd-messages plugin](https://github.com/LiquidChurch/lqd-messages/) and I see those methods in the [main plugin file](https://github.com/LiquidChurch/lqd-messages/blob/v0.9.0/gc-sermons.php).  Even if this isn't the correct file, hopefully explaining the order of execution of those will help explain when things are being called.

### File 1

The order of execution for that code looks like this:

1. The `GC_Sermons_Plugin->hooks` function is added in `plugins_loaded` on [L321](https://github.com/LiquidChurch/lqd-messages/blob/v0.9.0/gc-sermons.php#L321).
2. This adds a hook to `tgmpa_register` to run the function
   `register_required_plugin`, which checks the plugin's dependencies are
   installed (Uses [TGMPA](http://tgmpluginactivation.com/)) on [L186](https://github.com/LiquidChurch/lqd-messages/blob/v0.9.0/gc-sermons.php#L186).
3. If that check passes, then the method `GC_Sermons_Plugin->init` to the `init` hook on [L189](https://github.com/LiquidChurch/lqd-messages/blob/v0.9.0/gc-sermons.php#L189).
4. `GC_Sermons_Plugin->plugin_classes` is called, which is called inside of the `plugins_loaded` hook on [L190](https://github.com/LiquidChurch/lqd-messages/blob/v0.9.0/gc-sermons.php#L190).

In WordPress `plugins_loaded` occurs before `init` (not to be confused with `GC_Sermons_Plugin->init`, as that could potentially be called anything you want).

The code which is calling `GC_Sermons_Plugin->plugin_classes` is happening in this file in the WordPress hook `plugins_loaded`, and the `GC_Sermons_Plugin->init` function is being ran in the WordPress `init` hook.  This means `GC_Sermons_Plugin->plugin_classes` is called before `GC_Sermons_Plugin->init`.

### File 2

Looking at other repos under that organization, I assume the second plugin might be [LiquidChurch/lqd-messages-fns](https://github.com/LiquidChurch/lqd-messages-fns/) as I see code that fits your question there in [the main plugin file](https://github.com/LiquidChurch/lqd-messages-fns/blob/v0.5.1/liquidchurch-functionality.php).

1. Calls `LiquidChurch_Functionality->hooks` in WordPress' `plugins_loaded` hook on [L440](https://github.com/LiquidChurch/lqd-messages-fns/blob/v0.5.1/liquidchurch-functionality.php#L440)
2. calls `LiquidChurch_Functionality->init` in WordPress' `init` hook.
3. In the `LiquidChurch_Functionality->init` it calls
   `LiquidChurch_Functionality->plugin_classes`.

This was probably done in this manner so that LiquidChurch/lqd-messages-fns' code is ran *after* LiquidChurch/lqd-messages since the hook  `plugins_loaded` happens before `init` inside of WordPress.

### A Potential Problem

I don't know if there is an issue or not in the given scenario, but I wanted to touch upon one thing to look out for. If any of the classes that are loaded by `GC_Sermons_Plugin->plugin_classes` from the example from **File 1** add code to the WordPress hook `init` - this could be fired before *or* after the code from **File 2**, which is also ran in the WordPress hook `init`.

From what I recall, the plugins in WordPress are loaded in alphabetical sort order most of the time, but this is where using the `priority` argument for `add_action` and `add_filter` would be important.  Instead of relying on the fact that `plugins_loaded` happens before `init`, it would be better to rely on the fact that all of the code you want to run on `init` occurs in the order you want it to.  I see from the first plugin there are multiple composer dependencies, so those external codebases could be calling certain parts of code at any point in WordPress' execution.  Some could be before or after that you intended.

If we were to instead do this scenario:

```php
// Plugin 1
add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'plugin_classes' ), 10 );

// Plugin 2
add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'plugin_classes' ), 20 );
```

We would be using the priority argument to say run this code at priority 10 which gets executed before priority 20 - ensuring that Plugin 1's code is always executed on the same hook, and before Plugin 2 does.  This is generally the best approach to take instead of relying on the hook order being fired, or the alphabetical sort order of folder names for plugins.  There's nothing wrong with the given implementation overall, you just have to be careful to ensure that code is ran in the order you are expecting to avoid conflicts or weird scenarios.

Hopefully this explanation helps!